# History of the web map tile

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, history

I'm looking for a brief history of a 256x256 web map tile, in particular who used it first (came up with the idea) and who popularized it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_mapping#History_of_web_mapping

Comment: Which part of your question is most significant, the 256x256 "standard" tile size , use of web map tiles in general, or web mapping in general? If you could provide some reasoning for asking this question you would probably get better answers.

Comment: It is more to do with the projection (formula) 0,0 to 256,256 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#Formulas